# MaskedTextBox for validation in c#

Tags: c#

i am using maskedtextbox for name string and validating it for 10 characters are required and others are optional but when the user enter 10 character or more on then my defined message appears ("please enter 10 characters") how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried any? If yes, show us some code please.

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag please.

Answer (score 0):

You must use an "L" for each required letter and an "?" for each optional letter.
See [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/maskedtextbox-in-C-Sharp/) for more information.